# Using a single Data Model Schema to create multiple collections with different names

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a data model schema using mongoose for MongoDB. The data model is for a survey and the same survey is filled by people from 4 companies. Lets call them:

1. Company A
2. Company B
3. Company C
4. Company D

The important thing to note is that I will have a separate collection for each company within MongoDB (i.e company A, company B etc) makes it easier to find data for a particular company.

All those 4 collections will use the same Data Model Schema as they will be collecting exactly the same data. **How can I achieve this?**

**Data Model Schema:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var survey =  new mongoose.schema({

    sessionNo: {type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 6},
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    role: {type: String, required: true},
    programme: {type: String, required: true},

    q1: {type: String, required: true},
    q2: {type: String, required: true},
    q3: {type: String, required: true},
    q4: {type: String, required: true},
    q5: {type: String, required: true}
});
mongoose.model('userSatisfactionSurvey', survey);
```

Comment: not a good practice, if the schema is same just add `company` field and don't over-complicate stuff

Comment: @RohitHazra thanks for the commit. But that would add all the survey data into a single collection. There will be thousands of entires, wouldn't that cause a delays and issues with "GET"ting data? It will have to filter through so many entries to find all of the ones that belong to "Company A"

Comment: That is why you are using mongoDb, having one extra field is mostly a good option than to create a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

> not a good practice, if the schema is same just add company field and
>   don't over-complicate stuff

That being said all you have to is something like below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var survey =  new mongoose.schema({

    sessionNo: {type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 6},
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    role: {type: String, required: true},
    programme: {type: String, required: true},

    q1: {type: String, required: true},
    q2: {type: String, required: true},
    q3: {type: String, required: true},
    q4: {type: String, required: true},
    q5: {type: String, required: true}
});
var collectionOne = mongoose.model('userSatisfactionSurveyOne', survey);
var collectionTwo = mongoose.model('userSatisfactionSurveyTwo', survey);
var collectionThree = mongoose.model('userSatisfactionSurveyThree', survey);
var collectionFour = mongoose.model('userSatisfactionSurveyFour', survey);
```

Comment: @Skywalker if the answer helped you mark it as accepted. So others visiting this answer will know it worked